# Eratosthenes (prime-finder)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, bluej

The goal of the program is to find the prime-numbers below a certain maximum.
the `cancelNonPrimes()` method acts like it's working (in the step-by-step debugger) but just does not write the false-values to the list...

```
public class Era2
{
    int m;
    int i;
    boolean[] list;
   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Era2
    */
   public Era2(int max) {
     m = max;
     list = new boolean[m];
     initialize();
   }

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Era2 with standard-maximum-value = 25
    */
   public Era2() {
     m = 25;
     list = new boolean[m];
     initialize();
   }

   /**
    * Method for initializing an object: all values to true except 0 and 1
    */
   void initialize() {
       while (i < m) {
            setList(i, true);
            i = i + 1;
       }
       setList(0, false);
       setList(1, false);
   }

   /**
    * Method for setting a bool to a number on the list
    */
   void setList(int p, boolean b) {
        list[p] = b;
   }

   /**
    * Method for reading the entire list, printed in terminal
    */
   void getList() {
        for (int p = 0; p < m; p++){
         if (readList(p) == true){
            System.out.println(p + "true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(p + "false");
        }
        }
   }

   /**
    * Method for reading a specific shizl on the list
    */
   boolean readList(int p) {
    return list[p];
    }

   /**
    * Method for setting all non-primes to false
    */
   void cancelNonPrimes() {
    i = 2;
       while (i < m) {
       if (readList(i) == true) {
         int c = i;
         int n = 2;
         while (c < m) {
           c = (i * n);
           setList(c, false);
           n = n + 1;
         }
       }
      i = i + 1;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should remove `== true` for readability and use proper indentation

Comment: Why would you set 2 to false? Also, can you show the calling (/instantiating) method code? (Side note: BlueJ is not a Java "ripoff", it's an IDE. You are indeed programming regular Java, albeit with gruesome editor-support)

Comment: Working on my side after testing (that c < m when setting it to false). How do you call these methods ?

Comment: this pseudo code might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you never actually call cancelNonPrimes().

Comment: @yunandtidus: i call them in the BlueJ-interface, but how is the code working on your side when it's not working here?
Romiox: i can't show the calling method code, blueJ makes this when i compile i think, but this is all the code i have... calling methods i do in the BlueJ-interface.
sorry RC. for the stuff i write, i'm only a beginner ;)

Comment: @zeplor, on my side I called it with (in main method): Era2 e = new Era2(); e.cancelNonPrimes(); e.getList(); It worked

Comment: @yunandtidus well, i added a pointless if-statement because it still wasn't working here, and now it's working... Thanks yunandtidus!
btw i don't have to call the method with code, just with some clicks in BlueJ, but i wrote a new method which did    cancelNonPrimes() ; getList();     and it worked...